# Менять фон layout'а в виджет программно

Tags: java, android, layout

Всем привет. Возникла такая проблема, нужно при нажатии кнопки в самом приложении менять фон layout'а в виджете. Я пробовал, но никак не получалось. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Это должно помочь:

```
remoteView.setInt(R.id.ваш_виджет, "setBackgroundResource", R.drawable.ваша_картинка);
```

Comment: Не совсем помогло. remoteView красным отмечен.